# Monic polynomials with integer coefficients

Tags: polynomials

We have $\Pi_{j=1}^n (z-z_j)$ a polynomial with integer coefficients. Is also $\Pi_{j=1}^n (z-z_j^k)$ for k=1,2,3,... a polynomial with integer coefficients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.
The coefficients of the latter are symmetric polynomials in the $z_j$, hence are (integer!) polynomials in the *elementary symmetric polynomials* in the $z_j$, that is in the coefficients of the former polynomial.